# computing fundamental group of $S^1 \times S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology

How to find $\pi_{1}(S^{1}\times S^{1})$ ?

I know $\pi_1(S^1)$ but ho to do this ?

Comment: $\pi_1(A\times B)=\pi_1(A)\times \pi_1(B).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly it is isomorphic to $\pi_1(S^1)\times \pi_1(S^1)$ which is same as $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: ......Clearly?!

Comment: I don't agree with the downvote (I upvoted) but I agree that this statement may not clear to someone who would ask this question. Anyway, the "explanation" is that a map $S^1\to S^1\times S^1$ is the same thing as a pair of maps $S^1\to S^1$ and $S^1\to S^1$, and similarly a homotopy, $S^1\times I\to S^1\times S^1$ is the same thing as a pair of homotopies $S^1\times I\to S^1$ and $S^1\times I\to S^1$. (If this isn't obvious, then you should probably convince yourself of this.) Therefore, $\pi_1(S^1\times S^1)\cong \pi_1(S^1)\times \pi_1(S^1)$.

Comment: from next time you need to stay a bit more careful while writing your answer...you should always keep that in your mind that things might not be trivial for the person who asked a doubt, so you should try to be a bit more descriptive... It would be better if you edit your solution...btw welcome to mathstackexchange